# Get Basic Auth value sent in @Header from Android using Retrofit 2.0

Tags: php, android, web-services, retrofit2

How to get @Header value sent from Android using REST client Retrofit in php script to decode and verify?
below is the android API call.

```
public interface RetrofitClient {

    @GET("/checkUser.php")
    Call<UniversalRespModel> checkUser(@Header("Authorization") String auth);
}
```

where `String auth has Basic ==Wcvahsdustyu` some basic auth value.

How to get this value in PHP script?
Currently I tried for below code in PHP

```
$headerAuth=$_GET['Authorization'];
```

Comment: What issue exactly are you seeing?  Are you calling `checkUser` and passing in auth string as per method signature?

Comment: Yeah I am calling chekUser API and it is called I checked the same in POSTMAN by printing some random value. But I cannot get value of Authorization. Yeah and even the Basic Auth value is passed in API.

Comment: Can you show the code where you're invoking `checkUser`.  Are you saying that request is making it to server but you're not seeing the `Authorization` value?

Comment: Headers doesn't exist in the `$_GET`-super global. That's only for query parameters. You can access header values in the `$_SERVER`-super global in PHP.

Comment: Correct I am not seeing Authorization value and as Magnus said I even Tried with $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] as referred on some forums.

Comment: Guys please suggest. I need help to get it solved. Humble request

Comment: @AkshayMahale you can check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php